# Long sentence between "make" and adjective

Tags: translation, adjective-position

Consider the text below, which is an attempt of translation from Italian.

> This is needed **in order to make** all the editorial processes the
> manuscript will undergo **transparent**.

The boldface words show the connection with the *transparent* adjective, which is supposed to be connected with the *make* verb. But the sentence between the verb and the adjective seems too long, and therefore it could be uncomfortable or difficult for the reader to make this connection.

If we could use *them* to refer to the editorial processes, then we could say:

> This is needed in order to make them transparent.

which is much clearer.

But when there is a longer sentence in between, rather than a single pronoun, how can we make the text easier to read? Can *transparent* be placed immediately after *make*? (although I don't think so because the "object" being made "transparent" would end up after the adjective). Something like this:

> This is needed **in order to make transparent** all the editorial processes the
> manuscript will undergo.

Or perhaps the only way is to completely change the structure of the text? If this is the case, how would you change it?

Comment: Why do you think that there is something wrong with placing "transparent" immediately after "make"? Is it because you can't say "in order to make transparent it"? Grammar doesn't treat nouns and pronouns the same. You can say "I cleaned up the mess," but you can't say "I cleaned up it."

Comment: I was thinking that placing any noun or "object" (including pronouns) after the adjective would sound wrong, for example: "In order to make clean the house". And therefore the same would apply if you replace the noun/object with a whole sentence which has the same role/function. Perhaps I should also clarify this better in the question, I am going to edit it now.

Comment: From [the Bible](https://www.bible.com/bible/111/EPH.6.19-20.NIV): "so that I will fearlessly make known the mystery of the gospel". It's not always ungrammatical.

Comment: I don't find the original sentence with its moderately long object difficult. But there is the option to front the object. Given the editorial processes the manuscript will undergo, this is needed to make them all transparent.

Comment: I'm going with the original. It's straightforward. But could replace all that bold with **clarify** or **reveal**.  The words *In order to* don't add much.

Comment: I absolutely use the pattern "make transparent" all the time to solve precisely this problem. As a native speaker without real language training, all I can say is that it feels like an analogue of avoiding split infinitives.

Comment: Either seem fine to me. I would if possible (and context may affect this of course) say "in order to make the editorial process transparent".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The related expression 'make clear' is probably seen as a transitive 'phrasal verb' by some as it is so common and arguably unitary.

- 'Make Ø transparent Ø' (Ø showing alternative direct object slots)

is probably not considered unitary enough for the phrasal verb analysis, and is then analysed as being an object-orientated resultative structure, as with 'She shot him dead'.

With either analysis, the first DO slot (between 'make' and 'transparent/clear' is the only one available for pronouns, and is the only one that sounds natural in unmarked usage for DOs which are light noun phrases:

- *They shot dead him.
- *That makes plain it.
- ??/* They shot dead Joe.
- *She made clear things.
- They shot Joe dead.
- She made things clear.

But with weighty direct objects, the resultative adjective could get lost at the end of the clause, so is often promoted next to the [simplex] verb:

- (?)This is needed in order to make all the editorial processes the manuscript will undergo transparent.
- This is needed in order to make transparent all the editorial processes the manuscript will undergo.

(Neither of the above variants is complex enough to warrant an 'unacceptable.)

- */??He made all the conditions that attached to the funding for adult social care announced by the Chancellor in the Spring Budget of 2017 clear/transparent.

As ruakh says, moving the DO to the right of the particle ('looked it up'; 'looked up the relevant information') or resultative ('shot him dead'; 'shot dead all the insurgents attempting to break through the outer perimeter') falls under the class of shifts known together as **Heavy NP shift** (qv; [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift) gives an overview).

Comment: It was helpful to have an explanation strictly in terms of usage without trying to conjure up a rule.  Perhaps there is such a thing as 'having an ear' for meaning and expression.  There are, of course ways in which the sentence might be simplified, especially for spoken delivery.  But that is a different issue.

Comment: For those who'd like more information about this, the linguistics term for this phenomenon is "[heavy NP shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift)".

Comment: Beautiful and detailed explanation (although it took some time to me to fully understand it), and very useful comment by @ruakh that gives a name to the phenomenon. ruakh or Edwin please feel free to edit the answer to add that comment about terminology and the Wikipedia link (otherwise I am happy to edit it as well).

Answer (score 3):

One could write:

> This is needed to **ensure transparency in** all the editorial processes the manuscript
> will undergo.

i.e. convert “make _____ transparent” to “ensure transparency in _____”.

I’m not saying this is better than the original, and it involves changing the wording slightly, but it achieves the object of the question.

Comment: This is for ensuring transparency in editing of the manuscripts.

Comment: Very good suggestion!

Comment: @ARi — I agree (in part), and normally I would have done this sort of stylistic simplification myself (and likely got the dog's own abuse for my trouble). But I decided to restrict myself to the specific request.  In fact I find your "editing of the manuscripts" too much — no need for "of", and I dislike making a verb ("ensures") into an abstract noun. So I would edit yours to: "This is to ensure transparency in editing the manuscripts". But "needed" does express the idea of necessity, whereas "to" just shows the rationale, so perhaps needed is needed.

Answer (score -1):

As you suggested, you can rearrange the logical elements of the sentence. Here is one example.

**This will be needed to make all of the (manuscript) editorial processes (appear) transparent.**

The words in parentheses being optional for clarity, or perhaps another similar version would be more suitable.

Answer (score -2):

You don't need 'in order to' in your second sentence. So you can simply say:

> This is needed to make transparent all the editorial processes that the manuscript will undergo.